# Proof of the change of variables formula without using the Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I recently encountered the problem **Exercise 36** in Tao's *An Introduction to Measure Theory*. The link of an online version of this problem is [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/25/245a-notes-3-integration-on-abstract-measure-spaces-and-the-convergence-theorems/). Now I quote this problem as follows:

> **Exercise 36** (Change of variables formula)
> Let $(X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$ be a measure space, and let $\phi: X \rightarrow Y$ be a measurable morphism (as defined in Remark 8 from $(X, \mathcal{B})$ to another measurable space $(Y, \mathcal{C}). $ Define the pushforward $\phi_{*} \mu: \mathcal{C} \rightarrow[0,+\infty]$ of $\mu$ by $\phi$ by the formula $\phi_{*} \mu(E):=\mu\left(\phi^{-1}(E)\right)$
>
> 1. Show that $\phi_{*} \mu$ is a measure on $\mathcal{C},$ so that $\left(Y, \mathcal{C}, \phi_{*} \mu\right)$ is a
>    measure space.
> 2. If $f: Y \rightarrow[0,+\infty]$ is measurable, show that $\int_{Y} f d \phi_{*} \mu=\int_{X}(f \circ \phi) d \mu$

> (Hint: the quickest proof here is via the monotone convergence theorem below, **but it is also possible to prove the exercise without this theorem.**)

I really eager about how to prove the second statement WITHOUT the Monotone Convergence Theorem, in order to follow the procedure of the book. I tried hard and figured out only the case that $f$ is a simple function. How can we prove the case that $f$ is a general unsigned (nonnegative) function? The author have not provide the solution yet.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that, by definition, $\int_Y f \ \mathrm{d}\phi_*\mu:=\sup\left\{\int_Y s \ \mathrm{d}\phi_*\mu : s \text{ is simple and } 0 \leq s \leq f\right\}$.

You already proved that $\int_Y s \ \mathrm{d}\phi_*\mu=\int_X (s\circ \phi) \ \mathrm{d}\mu$ for any simple function $s$. If $s$ is simple with $0\leq s \leq f$, then clearly $s \circ \phi$ is simple and $0 \leq (s \circ \phi)\leq (f \circ \phi)$. Thus, by the definition above we get

$$
\int_Y f \ \mathrm{d}\phi_*\mu \leq \int_X (f\circ \phi) \ \mathrm{d}\mu. 
$$

**EDIT:** For the reverse inequality, my first two arguments were flawed. I think that I've fixed it. See details below.

Let $t: X \to [0, +\infty]$ be a simple function with $t \leq (f \circ \phi)$, say given by
$$
t:=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \chi_{E_k}
$$
where $\alpha_k$ is such that $0 \leq\alpha_k \leq f(\phi(x))$ when $x \in E_k$. Define
$$
F_k:=\{ y \in Y: f(y)\geq \alpha_k\}.
$$
Then each $F_k$ is measurable because $f$ is measurable. Define a simple function $s: Y \to [0,+\infty]$ by
$$
s:=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \chi_{F_k}.
$$
By construction $0 \leq s \leq f$. Further, notice that $E_k=\{ x \in X: (f \circ \phi)(x) \geq \alpha_k\}$ and therefore it follows that $\phi^{-1}(F_k)=E_k$. Thus, by definition of the measure $\phi_*\mu$ we get $\int_X t \ \mathrm{d}\mu = \int_Y s \ \mathrm{d}\phi_*\mu$. Thus, taking sup over all simple functions $t \leq (f \circ \phi)$ we conclude that
$$
\int_X (f\circ \phi) \ \mathrm{d}\mu \leq \int_Y f \ \mathrm{d}\phi_*\mu.
$$
This is the reverse inequality.

Comment: I think that I finally have a correct argument for the reverse inequality. This doesn't need to reduce to the case that $\phi$ is injective and therefore does not require quotients as in my second argument. I wasn't using the fact that $f$ is measurable before and this is the key step to get the simple function $s$.

Comment: OK thank you, I checked it and finally found you are right. Sorry because I was very busy the last few days, I did not log on the stack exchange then. I will do the same.

Comment: No worries! I am glad I finally got the answer. I was curious on how to do it without MCT. Turned out not to be hard at all. Of course the proof using MCT is just a couple of lines.

Comment: Thanks and congratulations to you. In my opinion, thinking about this is a good training on the “completion ” of the “systems” of mathematics in our mind.

Comment: $E_k$ is only contained in $\phi^{-1}(F_k)$ but may not be exactly equal. The argument still goes through since you only aim for an inequality.

Comment: @YuiToCheng It's been a while since I answered this one but I believe that $\phi^{-1}(F_k)=E_k$. As you said, $E_k$ is clearly contained in $\phi^{-1}(F_k)$. On the other side, if $x \in \phi^{-1}(F_k)$ then $\phi(x) \in F_k$ which implies that $f(\phi(x)) \geq \alpha_k$, whence $x \in E_k$. Thus $\phi^{-1}(F_k)$ is contained in $E_k$.